# DynamoDb documentClient.update or delete StringSet throws ValidationException

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, updates, amazon-lightsail, validationexception

I successfully update and delete an item from a StringSet in a dynamoDb table when called from my test app running on localhost.

I then upload the app to LightSail but now when I call the same function to update or delete an item it throws a ValidationException!:

```
{
"message": "Invalid UpdateExpression: Incorrect operand type for operator or 
function; operator: DELETE, operand type: MAP",
"code": "ValidationException",
"time": "2018-01-03T13:20:14.919Z",
"requestId": "9HCQMH5RAUBRK1K7BNESNBUD5BVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG",
"statusCode": 400,
"retryable": false,
"retryDelay": 10.381373865940402
}
```

Why? I have not made any changes to my code so why does this happen and how to solve it?

Here's the relevant code:

```
var documentClient = getDocumentClient();

var paramsSET = {
ExpressionAttributeNames:
{
  "#StringSet": "Packages"
},
ExpressionAttributeValues:
{
  ":value": documentClient.createSet(['filler as SET cannot be empty',
    app.packageName
  ])
},
Key:
{
  "EmailAddress": app.emailAddress
},
ReturnValues: "ALL_NEW",
TableName: "Developers",
UpdateExpression: "ADD #StringSet :value"
  // UpdateExpression: "DELETE #StringSet :value" ------ to delete value
};
  // adds packagename to Packages SET in developers table - creates set if not exist
documentClient.update(paramsSET, function (err, data){}
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not get it to work using the documentclient api.

finally used the old api and got it to work using dynamodb.updateItem see [docs here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html#updateItem-property)

still have no idea why it works on localhost (accessing the same dynamodb tables) and not when live on LightSail!